# изменение стиля css при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript

Создать класс(компонент) лампа, которая состоит из выключателя и самой лампы, при клике на кнопку лампа вкл/выкл

[image: примерно так должно выглядеть]

```js
button.onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = ('green');
};
```

```css
.circle{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Кнопка" />
 <div class="circle"></div>
```

получаеться поменять только цвет бекграунда самой страницы

Comment: Зачем вы создаете множественные [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942647/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-css-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js) на одну и ту же проблему?

Answer (score 3):

```js
function toggleButtonColor(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = el.style.backgroundColor == 'green' ? 'red' : 'green';
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  toggleButtonColor(document.querySelector('.circle'));
}
```

```css
.circle{
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid black 4px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="On/off" />
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо,а что означат знак вопроса в этой строчке?                                                     el.style.backgroundColor = el.style.backgroundColor == 'green' ? 'red' : 'green';

Comment: @Qtq Это называется [тернарной операцией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Если кратко, она призвана сократить код, - вместо блоков if/else вы можете использовать конструкции `? :`. Здесь она означает: "*цвет фона зеленый ? (если да) **вернуть красный** : (если нет) **вернуть зеленый***"

Answer (score 1):

Реализовано при помощи [Jquery](https://jquery.com/). Логика такова:

- На `div` вешаем событие `click`;
- По умолчанию кнопка выключена (кнопке с классом `btn` установлен класс `off`);
- По умолчанию лампочка выключена (лампочке с классом `lamoa` установлен класс `white`);
- По клику на кнопку лампочка включается (кнопке `btn` добавляем  класс `on`, а лампе `lampa` класс `yellow`;
- По повторному клику возвращаем дефолтные значения по тому же принципу.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  if(this.classList.contains('off')){
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on').text('ON');
    $('.lampa').removeClass('white').addClass('yellow');
  }
  else{
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off').text('OFF');
    $('.lampa').removeClass('yellow').addClass('white');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 99px;
  user-select:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.lampa{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 99px;
  user-select:none;
  cursor:none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.off{
  background-color: red;
}
.on{
  background-color: green;
}
.white{
  background-color: white;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div class="btn off">OFF</div>
    <div class="lampa white"></div>
</div>
```

Аналог на ванильном `JS`:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const lampa = document.getElementById('lampa');
btn.addEventListener('click',  function(){
  if(this.classList.contains('off')){
    this.classList.add('on');
    this.classList.remove('off');
    this.innerHTML = 'ON';
    lampa.classList.add('yellow');
    lampa.classList.remove('white');
  }
  else{
    this.classList.add('off');
    this.classList.remove('on');
    this.innerHTML = 'OFF';
    lampa.classList.add('white');
    lampa.classList.remove('yellow');
  }
});
```

```css
#btn{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 99px;
  user-select:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#lampa{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 99px;
  user-select:none;
  cursor:none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.off{
  background-color: red;
}
.on{
  background-color: green;
}
.white{
  background-color: white;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div id="btn" class="off">OFF</div>
    <div id="lampa" class="white"></div>
</div>
```

*P.S. Лампа горячая, поэтому курсора не видно*

Comment: можешь этот же Jquery показать на ванильном JS ?

Comment: @icedev-sk, могу.

Comment: напиши как комментарий или можешь заменить весь jquery, пожалуйста

Comment: @icedev-sk Готово)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const circle = document.querySelectorAll('.circle'),
  input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

input.forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (s.classList.contains('green')) {
      input.forEach((s, i, arr) => {
        arr[i].classList.remove('green');
        arr[i].value = 'выкл';
        circle[i].classList.remove('green');
      })
    } else {
      input.forEach((s, i, arr) => {
        arr[i].classList.remove('green');
        arr[i].value = 'выкл';
        circle[i].classList.remove('green');
      })
      s.classList.add('green');
      circle[i].classList.add('green');
      s.value = 'вкл';
    }

  })
})
```

```css
.circle {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.green.red {
  background-color: green
}

.red {
  background-color: red
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="red" type="button" value="Вык" />
  <div class="red circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="red" type="button" value="Вык" />
  <div class="red circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="red" type="button" value="Вык" />
  <div class="red circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="red" type="button" value="Вык" />
  <div class="red circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
button.onclick = function() {
  if (circle.style.backgroundColor == "green") circle.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  else circle.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#circle {
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid black 4px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="On/off"/>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Измените ваш ответ, так чтобы его можно было запустить.

Comment: Изменил........