# Не меняется стиль CSS через JS

Tags: javascript

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, другой элемент менял цвет background, а при еще одном нажатии менял назад.

Вот мой код:

```js
button.onclick = function(circle) {
  document.circle.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
};
```

```css
.circle{
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid black 4px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="On/off" />
<div class="circle"></div>
```